# Accessing different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro in Excel which is given a string value and searches for that (approx) string value in a column on a separate worksheet. If it finds a match it 'flags' that row.

The main problem I'm having is not being able to access the other worksheet in the macro.

Here's my `IF(OR ..)` statement I've done instead to give a basic idea of what I'm trying to do. I can access the other worksheet using `worksheetName`!

```
=IF(OR(EXACT(P3,'List of companies'!$A$1), EXACT(P3,'List of companies'!$A$2), EXACT(P3,'List of companies'!$A$3),...., "FLAG", "")
```

And here was my attempt at the macro

```
Sub searchandcompare()

Dim Worksheet As Workbook
Dim searchSheet As Worksheet

    Set searchSheet = Workbook.Worksheet("List of companies")

    For Each xCell In Selection

        For Each searchSheet In Range("A1:A65")

            If StrComp(xCell.Value, searchSheet) Then
                xCell.Offset(, -15).Value = "FLAG"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next searchSheet
    Next xCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub searchandcompare()

For Each xCell In Selection

    For Each searchSheet In Sheets("List of companies").Range("A1:A65")

        If StrComp(xCell.Value, searchSheet.Value) = 0 Then
            xCell.Offset(, -15).Value = "FLAG"
        Exit For
        End If

    Next searchSheet

Next xCell

End Sub
```